# RTP протокол

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте! Ктонибудь знает как организовать RTP протокол в C# мне нужно передовать звук реализовать web-call, SIP VOiP? 
спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Быть может, вам помогут следующие ссылки:

- [Using RTP in Multicasting](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Using_RTP_in_Multicasting.aspx)
- [Open Source VOIP Software](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/index.php?page_id=367)
- [Использование RTP в .NET](http://technosaratov.ru/thread/view/53/0/)
- [VoIP и C#](http://www.gotdotnet.ru/forums/3/80268/)